# How to activate python virtual environment in github action workflow

Tags: python, github-actions, virtualenv

I use local window pc as a self-hosted runner.

I installed python for all users

When I use python command in the same step which activate virtual environment, everything is fine.

But the python command in the separated step cause below error.
-> The term 'python' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

```yaml
- name: Set up Python ${{ inputs.python-version }}
      run: |
        py -${{ inputs.python-version }} -m venv .\venv
        & .\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip # It is OK
        python -m pip install tox
- name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip # It cause error
        python -m pip install tox
```

The "Set up Python" step results in success, but "Install dependencies" step causes error

I want to activate just once and use virtual environment in all steps
Is There any solutions?

Comment: Afaik; not possible. Activating venv is just setting up your shell settings and each step is essentially a new instance of a shell..

Comment: @rasjani setting up "setup-python" action looks stressful in self-hosted runner. I just need temporal python for CI/CD per pull request. Is there any brilliant something...?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74669486/7976758