# ImportError: No module named 'src' when running pytest in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, makefile, pytest, github-actions, virtualenv

I am encountering an issue when running my Python tests using pytest in GitHub Actions. The tests work correctly on my local machine, but in the GitHub Actions workflow, I receive an ImportError: No module named 'src' error.

```
    ============================= test session starts ==============================
  platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0 
    ...
    tests/test_compare.py:1: in <module>
        from src.functions.compare import imageCompare
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
    ...
```

**GitHub Actions Workflow:**

```
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - name: Get Code
          uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: Install Python
          uses: actions/setup-python@v4
          with: 
            python-version: 3.11
        
        - name: Activate Virtual Environment
          run: |
            python -m venv complianceEnv
            source complianceEnv/bin/activate
    
        - name: Install Dependencies
          run: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    
        - name: Run Tests
          run: |
            make test
```

Local Environment:

Python Version: 3.11.4
Operating System: MacOS
Virtual Environment: Yes

Directory Structure:

```
compliance-image-compare/
├── src/
│   └── functions/
│       └── compare.py
├── tests/
│   └── test_compare.py
├── Makefile
└── ...
```

also I already try to include the **init**.py in my filed locally, and it didn't work.

Comment: Need to activate `venv` in all the steps wherever it's needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668349/how-to-activate-a-virtualenv-in-a-github-action how you can set it once without the need to activate in each step.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files n your local source tree?

Comment: @Azeem yes I already try to do that.

Comment: Please include an UPDATE section in your question with those details. Thanks!

Comment: Did you activate `venv` in each step and run tests?

Answer (score 0):

Try following solutions:

1. Add **init**.py at the root of tests folder (usually this alone works)

```
    ├── tests/
    │   └── __init__.py
        └── test_compare.py
```

2. Specify your `src` folder in `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = "src"
```